# Page_Load alternatives

Tags: c#, windows-phone

So I have methods that need to be executed every time the application is opened up. `Page_Load` works, however I've realized when I quit the application on my phone, the application would still be running in the background until I stop all process from the application, ofcourse when the user heads back to the application it doesn't execute the `Page_Load` method because the app is already running.

I'm wondering if their is any way to detect when the user has loaded the application?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Page.OnNavigatedTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227508) if you want something to be executed each time your page is brought in the foreground (either freshly started or resumed).

Comment: "doesn't work" could mean a lot of things. Edit your question and post the code.

Comment: Well, the `onNavigateTo` is only called when I first open the application, however when exiting and continuing back to the application, it isn't called